# creation of 9x9 grid using angularjs ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried creating 9x9 table in ng-repeat with ng-model in angularjs. But grid/table created, I can't get the exact value from ng-model.

html code:

```
<tab ng-repeat="t in tabs">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="p in planets track by $index" >
<td ng-repeat="pl in planets track by $index" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{planets.pname}}" ng-model="t.planets.pname">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</tab>
```

js code:

```
  $scope.planets = [
    {'pname':'Kethu','tamil':'கேது'},
    {'pname':'Sukran','tamil':'சுக்ரன்'},
    {'pname':'Suriyan','tamil':'சூரியன்'},
    {'pname':'Santiran','tamil':'சந்திரன்'},
    {'pname':'Sevai','tamil':'செவ்வாய்'},
    {'pname':'Raagu','tamil':'ராகு'},
    {'pname':'Guru','tamil':'குரு'},
    {'pname':'Sani','tamil':'சனி'},
    {'pname':'Puthan','tamil':'புதன்'}
];
```

### My Expected output in ng-model:

```
tabs=[{"tabname":"T1","kethu":["kethu":0,"sukran":"5",...],"sukran":["kethu":2,"sukran":6,...]....},{"tabname":"T2",...}]
```

Comment: Looking at the code you have shared, I can see multiple issues. It will be better if you share more code / working sample / plunker. Also your `Expected output` doesn't look like 9x9 grid as you have mentioned in question header. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You should put

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{pl.pname}}" ng-model="pl.pname">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mXJiHXHzRXlIhsLbZnNH?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks...But It is replicating and I want like individual. For example 1st row of Kethu should have Kethu,Sukran..etc. values and 2nd row of Sukran can have Kethu,Sukran,Suriyan .. values.... Kethu will hold Kethu[Kethu,Sukran,Suriyan,Santhiran..], Sukran[Kethu,Sukran,Suriyan,Santhiran..] etc.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's basic programming in other form.

In nested for loops if you want to access (read/write) an element, you would need to pin point it by the enumerators of both loops

```
for (i=0; i<row.length; i++){
  for (j=0; j<column.length; j++){
    data[i][j] = something
  }
}
```

Same case in `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="(i, rowData) in row">
  <div ng-repeat="(j, columnData) in column">
    {{rowData.name}}, {{columnData.name}} <input ng-model="data[i][j]">
  </div>
</div>
```